# Matching a string without letter a

Tags: python, regex

How can I match the word section of 2 tokens being the letter `a` and a valid word.

For example;

- 'a dog' would return 'dog'.
- 'a pear' would return 'pear'

I'm currently looking through a large dataset and am looking to remove unnecessary letters in my machine learning classifier but the letter `a` is counting as a word in my 2 words.

How can I return the word without the a in Regex?

Comment: Please add other examples of input strings and theirs corresponding validation. As it stands you could simply use `if "dog" in "a dog"...`

Comment: Not well phrased - I meant what should be matched and what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Regex captures every `a`, `an` which is followed by a white space. It also checks if there is no letter in front of the `a` & `an` or if it's the first letter in the String.

```
(?:[^A-z]|^)(a|A|an|An)\s
```

This should basically cover every grammatically correct text.

Answer (score 0):

This one will do it, using positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=a\s)\w+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `regex` to replace `a`. The resultant will be a string with no `a` word:

```
import re
s = 'a dog'
removed_a = re.sub(r'\ba \b', '', s)
```

Note that `\b` matches word boundary. So above does match only word `a` and replace it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a word boundary `\b` to match `a` and not a in `testa dog` , then match a whitespace and capture the word after it in group 1 `(\w+)`.

For the replacement you could use the first capturing group:

[`\ba\b (\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/c4HHrG/1)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/HAK90338)